# Nodejs and heroku - Heroku not locating my css file and my image files but works fine on localhost port: 3000

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here, I have truly searched very hard but no answers forthcoming. I am writing a test web app. I have a css file and a few images (only 4)

The css file is located in the following: public/assets/css/styles.css
The image files are located in the following: public/assets/img/main.jpg etc

My code is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css">
```

and for the images:

```
<li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain1.jpg);"></li>
```

In my app.js file I also have the following:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

When I run the app on my localhost: 3000  it runs **perfectly**. When I push it to heroku I see all the html but it is not finding the css file or the image files:

[image: console in chrome]

I am really struggling to find an answer for this.

App.js

```
    var express             = require("express"),
      app                   = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Root Route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    // process.env.PORT
  console.log("Server has started");
});
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Mountain Travel</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Forked from a template on Tutorialzine: https://tutorialzine.com/2016/06/freebie-landing-page-template-with-flexbox -->
  <header>
    <h2><a href="#">Mountain Travel</a> </h2>
    <nav>
      <li><a href="#">Tours</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="hero">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/img/main.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="hero-content-area">
      <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
      <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="destinations">
    <h3 class="title">Some of our destinations:</h3>
    <p>Tired of the ocean? Are the plains too plain? Come along with us on one of our maintain adventures.
    Here are some picures from people who have had elevated experiences with us.</p>
    <hr>

    <ul class="grid">
      <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain1.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain2.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="large" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain3.jpg);"></li>
      <li class="small" style="background-image: url(assets/img/mountain4.jpg);"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="packages">
    <h3 class="title">Tour Packages</h3>
    <p>We offer a variety of mounteneering packages. whether you've climbed Everest or don't even know what a
    mountan is, we've got the perfect vacation for you.</p>
    <hr>
    <ul class="grid">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-compass fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Guided Trips</h4>
        <p>Looking for the complete experience? Take a tour with one of our experts. They'll show you the secrets
        that you're likely to miss otherwise.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Photo Trips</h4>
        <p>Want to experience nature's beaty without all of that annoying exercise? Take a photo tour on one of our
        mountain buses.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Biking Trips</h4>
        <p>If bicycles are more your speed, consider taking a tour through one of our mountain bike paths.
        We'll provide the bikes, and lunch too!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-flag-checkered fa-4x"></i>
        <h4>Racing Trips</h4>
        <p>Got a competitive spirit? Sign up for one of our mountain marathons! Try
        to reach the summit before anyone else.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section class="testimonials">
    <h3 class="title">Testimonials from our adventurers:</h3>
    <hr>
    <p class="quote">Wow! This tour made me realize how much I love mountains. After going on one of these
      tours, I can safely say they are my favorite geographic feature, and my favourite word that starts
      with M.</p>
    <p class="author">- Colt Steele</p>
    <p class="quote">I never understood why people cared so much about mountains. But then I went on one of
    these tours. Now I can't understand people who <em>don't</em> care about mountains!</p>
    <p class="author">- Ellie Schoppik</p>
    <p class="quote">If you want to understand the universe, head to the mountains! I mean, seriously. It's
    like, woah. You know? It's like that.</p>
    <p class="author">- Tim Garcia</p>
  </section>

  <section class="contact">
    <h3 class="title">Learn more</h3>
    <p>Want to know about our upcoming mountain-related events, or come to one of our mixers?
    Just sign up for our mailing list. No spam from us, we promise. Except for the spam we give you
  to keep up your energy while you're hiking through the mountains. We have tons of that.</p>
  <hr>
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Subscribe</a>
  </form>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>Images courtesy of <a href="http://unsplash.com/">Unsplash</a>.</p>
    <p>Why are you even reading this, there's never anything interesting in the footer!</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-square fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

That is all my code

Comment: can you try this:   const path = require('path'); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: share your entire app.js code, that might help narrow down the issue

Comment: tried that, same result - perfect on localhost but not on heroku

Comment: everything seems to be in place, can I ask you how are you deploying to heroku, using a pipeline or CLI?

Comment: Just pushing via git: git push heroku master

Comment: Only one more thing can be checked, if your repository is public, can you share the url

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you make express look in the public directory for assets (css/js/img), however your img and css aren't in this folder,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So try move your asset folder in the public folder.

Comment: my assets folder is in my public folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears solved.

I created a new directory and copied the entire old directory into the new one but the problem persisted.
I decided to create all the directories from scratch and then copied in the individual images and the css file into the proper place. redid all the npm init and installs and created a new heroku and it worked like a charm.

The only thing that I can think of is that originally I created my public directory with an uppercase "P" and then changed it to lowercase in finder afterwards. Somehow this was an issue even though I honestly don't understand why?